# Get the key from last child in Firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to be able to select randomly some data from my database on Firebase. For that and in order to avoid to download the whole database, I want to create entries with a key represented by an unsigned int like on this screenshot:

[image]

My question is, how can I retrieve the key of the last item added?

I tried:

```
ref.queryOrderedByKey().queryLimited(toFirst: 1).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { [unowned self] snapshot in
    let id: UInt64
    if snapshot.exists(), let child = snapshot.children.nextObject() as? FIRDataSnapshot {
        id = UInt64(child.key)!
    } else {
        id = 1
    }
})
```

but `UInt64(child.key)!`, whether I use `queryLimited(toFirst:)` or `queryLimited(toLast:)`, always returns 1.

What do I do wrong?

Comment: Seems the problem was coming from `observeSingleEvent`. When using  `observe` instead, I get the expected key.

Answer (score 1):

Your query returns the first result, which has key `1`. You're looking for `queryLimited(toLast: 1)`.

Additionally, in most cases, you should [avoid numeric, sequential keys in distributed data](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html).

Comment: As I said, even with 'queryLimited(toLast: 1)' it still returns 1 and not 2. I know it's not a good thing to have a numerical sequential key, but I didn't find another way to then be able to randomly retrieve data from Firebase.